# Maintaining the topology on a MultiLineString

Tags: topojson, topology, openlayers-6, multilinestring, leaflet-geoman

I'm trying to get topological movement of lines with Leaflet-Geoman plugin using TopoJSON. There is a [method](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#mesh) called `topojson.mesh` , which

> Returns the GeoJSON MultiLineString geometry object representing the mesh for the specified object in the given topology. This is useful for rendering strokes in complicated objects efficiently, as edges that are shared by multiple features are only stroked once. If object is not specified, a mesh of the entire topology is returned.

Thanks to answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543715/deduplicate-polygon-state-country-shared-boundaries) post, I've been able to return the MultiLineString using `topojson.mesh`. Since Leaflet-Geoman supports MultiLineString I came across with idea that may be the returned mesh can be edited with Leaflet-Geoman while maintaining the topological properties.

But when I try to accomplish it, the returned MultiLineString get separated in to two parts when I try to edit it using geoman plugin. My question is if that it is really a mesh that returned from `topojson.mesh` why the lines get seperated? Does that cause by geoman plugin? If that so, how can I get it done? Is there any way I can change the position of a node by dragging it while maintaining the topology?

I'll attach the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Topology Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/leaflet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free@latest/dist/leaflet-geoman.css" />

    <style>
        #mapdiv {
            height: 899px;
            background-color: #acd6e2;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapdiv"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3"></script>
    <script src="src/js/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free@latest/dist/leaflet-geoman.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapdiv', {
            layers: [
                new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                })
            ],
        });

        mymap.pm.addControls({
            position: 'topleft',
            drawCircle: false,
        });


        fetch("data/data.geojson")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {

                //var layer = L.geoJSON(json).addTo(map);
                var topo = topojson.topology([json]);

                console.log(json, topo, topojson.mesh(topo));

                var layerLines = L.geoJson(topojson.mesh(topo), {
                    fill: false,
                }).addTo(mymap);


                mymap.fitBounds(layerLines.getBounds());

            });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

data.geojson

```
 {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -113,
              37
            ],
            [
              -113,
              40
            ],
            [
              -109,
              40
            ],
            [
              -109,
              37
            ],
            [
              -113,
              37
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -109,
              37
            ],
            [
              -109,
              39
            ],
            [
              -104,
              39
            ],
            [
              -104,
              37
            ],
            [
              -109,
              37
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -109,
              34
            ],
            [
              -109,
              37
            ],
            [
              -102,
              37
            ],
            [
              -102,
              34
            ],
            [
              -109,
              34
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -104,
              37
            ],
            [
              -104,
              40
            ],
            [
              -100,
              40
            ],
            [
              -100,
              37
            ],
            [
              -104,
              37
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Like the name says `MultiLineString` there are multiple lines in the shape, so they are already sperated but displayed as one. But while editing, Geoman allwos to edit each line of the MultiLineString individual. What do you expect that Geoman should do?

Comment: `@FalkeDesign` What I assumed was, keeping everything like a mesh and moving all the nodes, without separating them in to multiple lines. That's why I used topoJSON here.

Comment: but moving is working for me, only editing shows the seperated lines

Comment: `@FalkeDesign`  Yes what I need is when editing, lines should not separate. Is that possible? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is not possible because `topojson.mesh` already creates two lines. You can only try to find a way to merge it to one line. But I don't know how

Comment: `@FalkeDesign` Thanks so much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for an answer to this type of question, I found a method using `OpenLayers v6.5.0`. Their is an example for [**Draw and Modify Features**](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html), which can maintain the topology of lines and polygons.

Hope this helps some one :)